# Swap dynamic amount of lines in text file

Tags: c#, random

I have a lot of text files with values, although the lines in the text file should be partially scrambled.

An example of a text file is as follows: (see the edit for an easier example)

```
0.00;1.2;3;2015-20-06 13:33:33
0.00;1.2;3;2015-20-06 13:33:34
0.00;1.2;3;2015-20-06 13:33:35
0.00;1.2;3;2015-20-06 13:33:36
[RAND]
0.00;1.2;3;2015-20-06 12:05:05
0.00;1.2;3;2015-20-06 12:05:22
0.00;1.2;3;2015-20-06 12:06:27
0.00;1.2;3;2015-20-06 12:05:42
[/RAND]
0.00;1.2;3;2015-20-06 12:25:36
0.00;1.8;3;2015-20-06 12:26:26
0.00;1.2;3;2015-20-06 12:28:05
[RAND]
0.00;1.8;3;2015-20-06 12:32:22
0.00;1.2;3;2015-20-06 12:33:04
[/RAND]
```

Everything between `[RAND]` and `[/RAND]` should be put in a random order.
So far I have the following but I have absolutely no idea how to continue from here or if this is even the right approach.

```
using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(LocalFile))
{
    bool InRegion = false;
        string line;
        while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            if (line.Equals("[RAND]"))
                    InRegion = true;

                if (line.Equals("[/RAND]"))
                    InRegion = false;
        }
}
```

One of my concerns is that I am using StreamReader and therefor cannot change the file.

There could be 2 lines but also 10 lines inside the `RAND` block and multiple `RAND` blocks per file.
Could somebody explain me how to go by this?

Thanks a lot in advance.

**EDIT:**

Easier example:

```
A
B
C
[RAND]
D
E
F
[/RAND]
G
H
```

It should then scramble the lines with D, E and F in a random order so you get something as follows:

```
A
B
C
E
F
D
G
H
```

Comment: What do you want to do exactly? I can't understand your question well

Comment: I added another example to make it a bit easier. Basically it should scramble the order of the lines between `[RAND]` and `[/RAND]` in .txt files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "bulky" way, leading to the most code (albeit readable), would be:

- Read all lines, close the file
- Find the blocks to randomize
- Randomize those blocks
- Write the result to a new file
- Move the new file over the old file

Something like this:

```
var linesInFile = File.ReadAllLines();

var newLines = new List<string>();
var toRandomize = new List<string>();

bool inRegion = false;

for (int i = 0; i < linesInFile.Count; i++)
{
    string line = linesInFile[i];

    if (line == "[RAND]")
    {
        inRegion = true;
        continue;
    }
    if (line == "[/RAND]")
    {
        inRegion = false;       
        // End of random block.
        // Now randomize `toRandomize`, add it to newLines and clear it     
        newLines.AddRange(toRandomize);
        toRandomize.Clear();
        continue;
    }

    if (inRegion)
    {
        toRandomize.Add(line);
    }
    else
    {
        newLines.Add(line);
    }
}

File.WriteAllLines(newLines, ...);
```

See [Randomize a List<T>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/273313/randomize-a-listt-in-c-sharp) to randomize the list.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Didn't realise I could read lines this way - very useful!

Answer (score 0):

I think its good to

**read all text of file at once**

**and get random areas with regular expression**

**and replace randomized result with it**

*above steps can be done by `Replace` method of `RegEx` class.*

**and finally save new content to file**

For example:

```
var regExp = @"(\[RAND\])(\w|\s|\d)*(\[/RAND\])";
var res = Regex.Replace(str, regExp, match =>
{
       // suffle the and return result
       // the return string replaced with occuring rand area
       // for example with suffle algorithms
       return "Randomized";
 });
```